# Finding the smallest number lexicographically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print smallest number. My prof calls it lexicographical order I think.

For example, I have this list :

```
[27312,31539]
[49494,26089]
[2946,28149]
```

The result should be:

```
27312
26089
28149
```

Why 28149 is smaller than 2946 so, 2 = 2, but the next int 8<9 ,so it prints 28149.

Is it possible to implement this using lambda ?

Comment: Is `lambda` compulsory? Because, it does not look like a good use case for `lambda`s.

Comment: As I see it can be solved also without ,thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `min` function with `str` as a key function:

```
print(min([27312,31539], key=str))
print(min([49494,26089], key=str))
print(min([2946,28149], key=str))
```

This outputs:

```
27312
26089
28149
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think that it can be solved so easily.
It's strange how it works, i mean by key of str

Comment: With lambda - `func = lambda array: min(array, key=str)`